# Why Properties.store delimiting with \ for values separating with :

Tags: java

I have a file which contains properties like :

```
MyKey=value1:value2
```

I am using Properties.load to load these into a property object and then outputting the values into another file (using **Property.store** ).

But the new file is delimiting it with `\`

```
MyKey=value1\:value2
```

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because `:` is like `=` a reserved char.

```
 Truth = Beauty
  Truth:Beauty
 Truth                    :Beauty
```

All these lines will set the value for the Property with the Key `Truth` to `Beauty`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)

The write method will escape the `:` sign to  `\:`. After loading this chars will be removed.

Comment: So delimiting it with \ is valid ( or is it something to do with 8859-1 encoding which Property.store uses ?